# Getting rights for display for 2nd user in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

**How can you get rights for the 2nd admin-user in Ubuntu?**

My window-manager is Ion3.

I get the following errors for X11 applications run by the second admin-user.

```
masi@masi-desktop:/home/noa$ firefox
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
```

This suggests me that you need to have rights to the display.
However, `su -c xterm` is not working, since the root password is disabled in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by giving every process an access the display by

```
 sudo xhost +
```

However, this can be a security threat, since any process in your network can then access your Screen and possibly too other input devices such as mouse.

Comment: the new question is at http://superuser.com/questions/85818/allow-only-one-extra-user-to-access-the-display

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo`; however you should not need to be root to get the display. I'm unaware of Ion3, but I'm sure more errors will crop up after you get root, in which case you can update your question.

Comment: This is strange: I have two users masi and isam, both are admins. isam can start firefox without sudo, but masi cannot. Perhaps, there are other settings which I do not know.

Comment: Which one is which? And which one is logged into X first? Usually a display is owned by one user at a time