# Allow only one extra user to access the display

Tags: ubuntu, display, xhost

The question is based on [the thread](https://superuser.com/questions/77975/getting-rights-for-display-for-2nd-user-in-ubuntu).

**How can you allow only one user to access the display by xhost?**

`sudo xhost masi` is not working in my fresh Ubuntu 9.10.

Comment: what is the output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm testing on Ubuntu 12.04 with X.Org X Server 1.11.3.

I tried Johan's solution and it appeared at first to work, but I found on my system the text after "local:" was being ignored. The result was that all local users were given access to my X session rather than one user.

The magic I found worked was:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:masi
```

Replace the portion after the last colon with the username you wish to grant access. You can inspect the authorised list by running xhost with no paramters. It should look something like:

```
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:masi
SI:localuser:myself
```

This indicates that the "masi" user and the "myself" user are being granted xhost permissions in the same way.

Comment: Note that (at least on Mint 17) the new user (masi in this case) has to have access to the Xauthority file

Comment: how to add if xhost command not found..:(

Answer (score 5):

Basically the same as John T, but you could add inet or local to the command

```
xhost +inet:masi@
xhost +local:masi@
```

Comment: +1 -- Adding the @ sign fixed it for me: xhost +masi@.  Not sure why this tidbit isn't in the man page...

Answer (score 1):

First, restrict X server access to those who aren't on the list:

```
sudo xhost -
```

then add yourself to the allow list:

```
sudo xhost +masi
```

Comment: It gives me `xhost: bad hostname "masi"` although my admin user is `masi`.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Regardless of that error message it works. To be fair, it worked on one debian machine, but failed on another ubuntu machine. It may be some firewall or extra config. In case that this is not a shared machine you could completely disable xhost control by running `xhost +`. Any user running on your machine will be able to play X displays. Do not use in shared machines or whatever.